# Rich notification action not clickable

Tags: android, notifications

I'm using Jelly Bean's rich notification system and I'm adding two actions to my notification. The problem I have is the actions seem to be disabled.

The idea is to set a `PendingIntent` to each one of the actions and get notified in a BroadcastReceiver which I registered to handle the actions in the two intents.

Here is the code for creating the notifications:

```
        Intent startIntent = new Intent(Notifications.START);
        Intent resetIntent = new Intent(Notifications.RESET);

        PendingIntent startPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx,
                whichOne, startIntent,
                Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REPLACE_PENDING);
        PendingIntent resetPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx,
                whichOne, resetIntent,
                Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REPLACE_PENDING);

        [...]

        notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(ctx)
                .setContentTitle(s)
                .setContentText("")
                .setContentIntent(appIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)

                .addAction(R.drawable.play,
                        ctx.getString(R.string.START), startPendingIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.reload,
                        ctx.getString(R.string.RESET_TIMER),
                        resetPendingIntent);
        [...]
```

Then I register the `Receiver` like this:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(Notifications.START);
    filter.addAction(Notifications.RESET);

    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(context, intent.getAction(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

        }
    };

    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

The problem I have is the actions seems to be disabled. I cannot click them and they are displayed with the typical disabled alpha text color.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REPLACE_PENDING` flag from your `PendingIntent` for both actions and replace it with 0. [That flag is most commonly used with sticky broadcasts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_RECEIVER_REPLACE_PENDING) where the most recent value is the only one that matters (e.g. checking battery level).

Removing that flag will re-enable your actions.  If your intent was to only make one action available at any given time then I suggest using a static ID for that notification so that only one notification of that type can be used at any given time.